# ServiceStack: Dto.ToAbsoluteUri throws exception complaining about AppHost

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to get the AbsoluteUri from a dto object.

As expected, all of these give me the RelativeUri:

```
dto.ToUrl();
dto.ToGetUrl();
dto.ToRelativeUri("GET");
```

Naturally I would expect `dto.ToAbsoluteUri("GET");` to give me exactly what I want but it throws an exception with message:

> ServiceStack: AppHost does not exist or has not been initialized. Make sure you have created an AppHost and started it with 'new AppHost().Init();'  in your Global.asax Application_Start() or alternative Application StartUp

My solution at the moment is to do this:

`$"{Client.BaseUri[..^1]}{dto.ToUrl()}";`

Note: `Client` is a `JsonServiceClient`

I know this is minor and I can easily work around it but shouldn't this work or is there a different way I'm missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The be able to resolve the Absolute URL, the `ToAbsoluteUri()` extension method needs to access the AppHost to use any configured Base URL, i.e:

```
var absoluteUrl = HostContext.ResolveAbsoluteUrl("~/".CombineWith(relativeUrl), req);
return absoluteUrl;
```

The other extension methods referenced only return the relative URL which doesn't need it.

There's no way for ServiceStack's client libraries to know the Absolute URL is so combining the BasePath with the relative URL extension methods is the correct approach.